# Convert Field string Json to Parse Format in c# or SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, .net-core, c#-4.0

This is a multilingual data format saved in the database and I am using
dapper to fetch the name.Below is the output when fetch.

```
"firstName":"{
    \"ar-AE\": \مستم"\",
    \"en-US\": \"test\"
}"
```

I need in  parse format in below mention (Expected output)

```
"firstName":{"ar-AE": "مستم","en-US":"test"}
```

This is the DTO class

DTO.cs

```
class DTO
{
    public string FirstName
}
```

while fetching from dapper it is returning in list.
so from the response list I can do like this

```
list.select(x=> JSON.Deserialize<string>(x.firstName))
```

how i can change the existing list to parse JSON so that I can get the
expected output

SQL: simple select query I am using also or also suggestion for SQL

```
select FirstName from TableA
```

Any suggestions from CSharp OR SQL?

> i need an output like this returning from list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to convert the first string, but it is not recognized as a JSON string. Then I tried the reverse, with string_escape(`<json string>`, 'json') and got a different string from your's.

Is it possible that the first string got malformed in this post? The double quotes surrounding `مستم` seem to be misplaced. When I change the position from `\مستم"\"` to `\"مستم\"`, I get a valid json object. I expect it has to do with reading right-to-left and the double quote got moved to the begin of the value.

T-SQL code to validate

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'"firstName":"{    \"ar-AE\": \"مستم\",    \"en-US\": \"test\"  }"';
declare @path nVARCHAR(max);

print 'isJSON( '''+@json+''')  --> '+case isJSON(@json) when 0 then 'false' when 1 then 'true' else 'unknown' end;
print 'add missing {} '
set @json = case when isJSON(@json) = 0 then N'{'+@json+N'}' else @json end;
print 'isJSON('''+@json+''') --> '+case isJSON(@json) when 0 then 'false' when 1 then 'true' else 'unknown' end;

set @path=N'$';
select @json                        as [@json]
     , @path                        as [@path]
     , json_query(@json, @path)     as [json_query]
     , json_value(@json, @path)     as [json_value]

set @path=N'$.firstName';
select @json                        as [@json]
     , @path                        as [@path]
     , json_query(@json, @path)     as [json_query]
     , json_value(@json, @path)     as [json_value]
```

and reverse

```
declare @json nvarchar(max);
-- now paste the expected result in a variable
set @json = N'"firstName":{"ar-AE": "مستم","en-US":"test"}'

-- test if the string is a valid JSON object
select isJSON(@json) as [original is JSON?]
     , isJSON(N'{'+@json+N'}') as [modified is JSON?]

-- the surrounding {} are missing, adding them now
set @json = N'{'+@json+N'}'

-- ways to query the JSON object
select * from openJSON(@json);
select JSON_QUERY(@json, N'$') as [JSON-query];

select string_escape(@json, 'json') as [expected input]
```

Comment: It is, in fact, a right-left issue. You can see this effect in Notepad by pasting مستم into an SO comment or Notepad and then moving the cursor around. There doesn't seem to be a standard way to encode JSON strings that have both directions. If you have access to the way the data formatted in the database, maybe you can escape/encode somehow.

Comment: The sql server function `string_escape` does return the string correctly, maybe you can use that in your query. Don’t know dapper.

Comment: @Kit check the output image  i have shared what exactly i need it

Comment: @Bas that doesnot seem work to me

Comment: i found the solution in c# by using Mapping             .ForMember(j => j.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.FirstName == null ? new MultilingualString() :JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultilingualString>(f.FirstName))) using deserialization it works

Answer (score 0):

When you have stored the JSON object in the `firstName` column, you can prevent SQL Server from escaping the content of the `firstName` column, by using the `JSON_query` function in combination with `for JSON path`.

`JSON_query` tells `for JSON` it's result is a valid JSON object and it doesn't need to be escaped.

Example:

```
with TableA
as ( select [firstName] = N'{"ar-AE": "مستم","en-US":"test"}' )

select [firstName] = JSON_query(firstName)
  from TableA
   for json path
```

Result:

```
[{"firstName":{"ar-AE": "مستم","en-US":"test"}}]
```

To prevent the result is presented as an array `[..]`, add `, without_array_wrapper` to `for JSON path`